# Linux flash player mozilla firefox plugin appears blue

Tags: linux, flash, youtube, media-player, mozilla

So I've added the flash player plug-in to my mozilla firefox on linux. It worked, but caused a problem, now the player is visible from other windows (partially), and the player it self appears a little blue.

When the screen goes to sleep (black screen) you can see the flash player on top of the black screen..?, when minimizing the browser then any black outlines on any window are replaced with the flash player content (for example the borders of the console).

It seems that the flash player position on the browser page does change it's position every where else, but scrolling the page down it not helping to get rid of the flash player completely, half of it will still get stacked and be visible.

It that a known problem? Can this be fixed?

p.s. a screenshot doesn't capture this happening.

Comment: Perhaps compatibility issues? What is your version of firefox and the version of flash plugin?

Comment: Firfox - 24.2.0
Shockwave Flash - 11.2 r202

Comment: Oh flash, I remember you.  RIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

Right click on the flash (youtube) -> Settings -> uncheck 'Enable hardware acceleration'

-> no more blue people, or flash over screen saver!